# WebView and Native Login - best way to authenticate

Tags: android, rest, web-services, security

I have a website and I am going to develop a webview based app. Right now, my website has a login screen.

But I would like to create a native login to enter to website.

Native Login -> Login OK -> Open dashboard on website -> store session on my native app

I am thinking about use a webservice passing the login e password, if it's correct...what should I know?

-- Add cookies to the webview and automatically login? 
-- Redirect to a URL that will log automatically by a token?

What do you guys suggest? Yes, I saw many answers. But I want to know the best way. I don't want to know about how to code it. But the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A webserver, like tomcat for java or apache with php seems to agree with your requirements but you should give more specific details.